# Using Mathematical Induction for a proof

Tags: prime-numbers, induction

How can I use Mathematical Induction to prove that there are an infinite number of prime numbers?

Comment: You can try [Euclid's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 2):

We will show that the number of primes is at least $N$ for every finite $N$, and so must be infinite. There clearly is a prime, so the base case is established.

Now suppose there exist $N$ primes $p_1, ..., p_n$. Define $P = p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdots p_n + 1$ and note that $P > 1$ is divisible by a prime. But it's not divisible by $p_k$ for $1 \le k \le n$, so there must be at least one more prime, establishing the existence of $N + 1$ primes.

Comment: Just to add that this is a classic example of a kind of mathematical induction called transfinite induction. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction